# Add custom attributes to Magento Categories

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create a new tab for categories that contain image upload fields. I have created a custom module and I can see it in the configuration. I have added the read and write permissions in my module config and also matched the version number in my installer script, which looks like

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'nav_image',  array(
    'group'     => 'Promo Images', 
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'Nav Image',
    'input'     => 'image',
    'backend'   => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'global'    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => TRUE,
    'required'          => FALSE,
    'user_defined'      => FALSE,
    'default'           => ''
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'nav_image',
    '2'
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

I cannot see the new tab at all in the categories section and I am not sure what is going on. here is the relevant section from my module config

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <test_navimages_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Test_NavImages</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </setup>
        </test_navimages_setup>
        <test_navimages_setup_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </test_navimages_setup_write>
        <test_navimages_setup_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </test_navimages_setup_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Can anyone spot what's going on or offer any assistance? (Magento 1.9)

Comment: Your installer script says you're creating a new category attribute, nothing about creating a new tab group.

Comment: I have already managed to create a tab using an observer which works fine, the problem is trying to get the new field in the tab and the extra columns in the DB. This is completely new to me, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly